# Powershell reading from a XML

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to read from an XML file and make an output of the information.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ModelList>
 <Model name="ThinkCentre M715Q">
  <Types>
   <Type>10M4</Type>
   <Type>10RA</Type>
   <Type>10RB</Type>
   <Type>10M5</Type>
   <Type>10RC</Type>
   <Type>10M2</Type>
   <Type>10RD</Type>
   <Type>10M3</Type>
  </Types>
 </Model>
</ModelList>
```

I managed to get the output of the model attribute with the following powershell code.

```html
[xml]$xmlFile = Get-Content -Path C:\Temp\data.xml
$xmlFile.GetType().Attributes
$xmlFile.ModelList.Model | Format-Table
```

Output information with the current code above:

```html
name              Types
----              -----
ThinkCentre M715Q Types
```

But... As you can see, the Types attribute is just types. I also want to be able to read the nested information inside of the ModelList. I want the output to be more like this:

```html
name              Types
----              -----
ThinkCentre M715Q 10M4, 10RA, 10RB, 10M5, 10RC...
```

I am stuck here. I need guidance to just simply bind the attributes. That Types attribute knows it is associated with the Model of ThinkCentre. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You've tagged three different versions of PowerShell, which isn't particularly helpful, especially as none are the most recent versions of PowerShell (5.1 for Desktop and 7.2 for Core, respectively). Which version are you actually targeting?

Comment: Hi, sorry. I am on targeting currently on 5.1. I also removed the tags for less confusion.

Comment: ```$xmlFile.ModelList.Model.Types.Type``` will return an array containing the text from each ```<Type>``` element - you can use that to do whatever downstream formatting / output you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your XML could contain more models and types, you would need to loop over the nodes.

Also, there is a better way to load the xml than using `Get-Content` that automatically takes the documents encoding into account:

```
# load the xml file. This way, you are ensured to get the file encoding correct
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new()
$xml.Load('C:\Temp\data.xml')

foreach ($model in $xml.ModelList.Model) {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Model = $model.Name
        Types = $model.Types.Type -join ', '
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Model             Types                                         
-----             -----                                         
ThinkCentre M715Q 10M4, 10RA, 10RB, 10M5, 10RC, 10M2, 10RD, 10M3
```

Comment: You explained exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thank you so much. Working like a charm!
Question, when would you suggest to use the Get-Content cmdlet? Is it better to use that specific for text files? Cause I've seen some posts that people even use this for reading xml content also.

Comment: @Obbo Basically yes. Get-Content doesn't check the encoding of the xml. Like this you can't fail. Btw. May I point you to the [tour] where you can find out all about this platform? There you can also see how to mark this question 'done' so others with a similar question can benefit as well